# How to create multiple html elements inside another , with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to dynamically construct a table row like this:

```
        var row = $("<tr>");
        row.html(
            $("<td>").html("cell 1") +
            $("<td>").html("cell 2") 

        );
        return row;
```

it doesn't work with multiple `$("<td>")`'s. It yields a table row with html of `Object object`.

However, it works with only one `td`. So I think this is possible, but I don't know how.

Any idea how to make this ?

I also tried append and add.

Thanks for any help !

### Edit:

I was doing it before like this :

```
return "<tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr>" /* etc.. */ ;
```

but this becomes a horrible / unreadable / uneditable code with attributes and such.

Comment: And somebody downvoted all the answers and the question. I +1'd all the help. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you are having jQuery objects use .append()

```
var row = $("<tr>");
row.append($("<td>").html("cell 1")).append($("<td>").html("cell 2"));
return row;
```

---

A slightly different version is

```
var row = $("<tr>");
row.append($("<td>", {
    html: "cell 1"
})).append($("<td>", {
    html: "cell 2"
}));
return row;
```

Comment: Nice and fast. Thanks ! I prefer multiple append lines though. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @redaxmedia where are the additional html calls

Comment: $("<td>").html("cell 1") equals $("<td>cell 1</td>") ... better performance while using less method calls.

Comment: @redaxmedia thanks, but my concern in this case was code readability, not performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways...

```
1. children.appendTo(parent);

2. parent.append(children);

3. parent.html(children);
```

In your case something like that should work:

```
var row = $('<tr>');

$("<td>Hello world</td>").appendTo(row);
```

No need for return :-)

Answer (score 0):

just do it like this

```
$("<tr><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>lol</td></tr>").appendTo($("something"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I especially stated that this is bad code for me, since I need to edit it often.

Comment: What? You can do anything like this. For example

    var output = "<tr>";

    output += "" +
    "<td>Cell 1</td>"+
    "<td>" + "something " + "</td>";

    output += "" +
    "</tr>";

    $(output).appendTo($(something));

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the code becomes unreadable. It takes minutes to change a single variable's name per se.

Comment: that's completely inaccurate you obviously don't have a clue what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

here is a functional way of going about doing this:

```
//data is an array of text/data/whatever
function createRow(data) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    var td;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        td = $("<td>").html(data[i]);
        row.append(td);
    }
    return row;
}
```

then just append the returned row to whatever html element you want

see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHLec/)

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, the HTML will not be cell 1 , cell 2. I need to write the content manually.

Comment: just pass all the content you want (for example `data=["my first content", "something else"]`) to the function. it will spit out a row for you. if you need to change the number of table data elements created or the content, you just change the data array you pass in to something else.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry I didn't read your answer carefully. Thanks again !